# Can I make a Grid Tap gesture send a command and then cause an element to become invisible?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this template that I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t:BaseButtonTemplate xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                       xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
                       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
                       x:Class="Japanese.Templates.Btn" x:Name="this">
    <StackLayout Padding="10"
                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding TapCommandParam, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                                  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <Frame CornerRadius="25" 
               BorderColor="{Binding FrameBorderColor, Source={x:Reference this}}"
               BackgroundColor="{Binding FrameBackgroundColor, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HasShadow="false" Padding="0"
               WidthRequest="50" 
               HeightRequest="50">
                <Label TextColor="{Binding LabelTextColor, Source={x:Reference this}}"
                       Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                       HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontFamily="FontAwesome5ProRegular" />
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</t:BaseButtonTemplate>
```

Here's the back-end for the XAML:

```
public partial class BaseButtonTemplate : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonHeightRequestProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ButtonHeightRequest), typeof(string), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate), "");
    public static readonly BindableProperty EnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Enabled), typeof(bool), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate), default(bool));
    public static readonly BindableProperty FrameBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FrameBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate), Color.FromHex("FFFFFF"));
    public static readonly BindableProperty FrameBorderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FrameBorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate), Color.FromHex("FFFFFF"));
    public static readonly BindableProperty LabelTextColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LabelTextColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate), Color.FromHex("FFFFFF"));
    public static readonly BindableProperty ParamProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Param), typeof(string), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate), default(string));
    public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandParamProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TapCommandParam), typeof(object), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate), default(object));
    public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create( "TapCommand", typeof(Command), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, defaultValue: default(Command));
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate), default(string));

    public Color FrameBackgroundColor { get { return (Color)GetValue(FrameBackgroundColorProperty); } set { SetValue(FrameBackgroundColorProperty, value); } }
    public Color FrameBorderColor { get { return (Color)GetValue(FrameBorderColorProperty); } set { SetValue(FrameBorderColorProperty, value); } }
    public Color LabelTextColor { get { return (Color)GetValue(LabelTextColorProperty); } set { SetValue(LabelTextColorProperty, value); } }
    public Command TapCommand { get { return (Command)GetValue(TapCommandProperty); } set { SetValue(TapCommandProperty, value); } }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public object TapCommandParam { get { return (object)GetValue(TapCommandParamProperty); } set { SetValue(TapCommandParamProperty, value); } }
    public string ButtonHeightRequest { get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonHeightRequestProperty); } set { SetValue(ButtonHeightRequestProperty, value); } }
    public string Param { get { return (string)GetValue(ParamProperty); } set { SetValue(ParamProperty, value); } }
    public string Text { get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); } set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); } }

}
```

Is there a way using bindings that I could make it so that when there has been a tap gesture the command would be sent but also the frame is made to be invisible. From my limited knowledge I think this may be impossible but I am interested to know if anyone can think of a way to do this.

Comment: Can you bind IsVisible property of your frame, and set that to false on tap command.This should work

Answer (score 1):

Well simply what you can do is something like this:

- Inherit INotifyPropertyChanged into your class.
- Implement its methods something like this:

  ```
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
  PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
  if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  private bool _isvisible=true; //so that by default it is visible
  public bool IsGridVisible { get {return _isvisible;} set {_isvisible=value; 
  RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsGridVisible));}}
  ```
- Then bind this to whatever control you want to hide:
- Then On Tap Gesture command change the value of this to false;

  void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
     IsGridVisible = false;
  }

This should be more than enough for your code to work like a charm.

Revert in case of queries.